# Getting the error: Possible Unintended Reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the error: Possible Unintended Reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Here's the code generating this error

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.["Theme"] == "Classic")
    {
        MasterPageFile = "Classic.master";
    }
    else if (Application["Theme"] == "Night")
    {
        MasterPageFile = "Night.master";
    }
}
```

I tried putting .ToString after ["Theme"] but then it says "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string'

Comment: Try: if ((string)(Application["Theme"]) == "Classic")

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, it's a Resharper warning. It means you're comparing an `object` to a `string`, which is going to compare the references, when you actually want to compare the two strings' values. To do this, you need to cast the object to a string first.

You need to actually call the method, not compare the method to your string:

```
if (Application["Theme"].ToString() == "Classic")
```

Comment: This can throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Maarten Whether or not a null check is appropriate is for the asker to decide and is beyond the scope of both the question and the answer. The intention of the above snippet is to illustrate the difference between calling the method and referencing the method, not to arbitrarily address a load of potential issues with the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try to use Equals:

```
Application["Theme"].ToString().Equals("Night")
```

Comment: This can throw a NullReferenceException.